# How to exclude particular word with special character from a capture group in REGEX?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create Regex for below text:

```
date=2016-02-25 time=10:14:22+0000
```

In this we need to capture like below(Single Capture Group)

```
2016-02-25 10:14:22
```

I have tried below Regex but i cannot able to achieve my O/P:

```
^(?!time=)\D+(\d{4}\-\d+\-\d+\s\D+\d+\:\d+\:\d+)
```

Is it possible to create Regex? Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could just capture both date and time with separate groups and join them together using Python's string operators:

```
import re

text = 'date=2016-02-25 time=10:14:22+0000'
pattern = r'^date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) time=(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[+-]\d{4}$'

match = re.match(pattern, text.strip())
result = " ".join(match.groups())

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.*?((?:\d+-?)+).*?((?:\d+\:?)+).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ3zD0/1)

**Explanation:**
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)